# What is the difference between keyCode and event.getKeyCode in Android?

Tags: android, android-view

In the View.OnKeyListener interface, there is a method defined like this:

```
abstract boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
```

What is the difference between the keyCode paramater, and event.getKeyCode()?

Why is there 2 keyCodes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `keyCode` value is the same as the `event.getKeyCode()` value.

The `KeyEvent` contains full information about the key event, including the key code that caused the event.

I suspect that the `keyCode` parameter was included in the `onKey()` method signature because it just made sense to include the most salient information. Also, there are probably a lot of callback implementations that only need the key code.